# Even permutations and possible determinants of it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How many permutations of $(1,2,3,4)$ are even and what are they?

Okay so half of the permutations would be even which are $\frac{4!}{2}=12$
I understand this problem w/o any concerns but :

*What are all the possible 4 by 4 determinants of $I+P_{even}$*

So first of all what is meant by $P_{even}$? How do I express $P_{even}$ as a matrix?

Comment: Probably $P$ is the associated permutation matrix. So for a permutation $\pi$, $P(i,j) = 1$ if $\pi(i)=j$ and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

$P_{even}$ means a permutation matrix derived from an even permutation. The even permutations in this case are obtained from 1234 by an even number of swaps:

```
1234 1342 1423
2143 2314 2431
3124 3241 3412
4132 4213 4321
```

The permutation matrices are constructed as described by Alex in the comments. For example, $P_{even}$ for the permutation 3124 is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Since 1 maps to 3 under the permutation, the third column of the first row is 1. Since 2 maps to 1, the first column of the second row is 1, and so on; everywhere else is zero. Adding the identity matrix to this, as you want, produces
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

The determinants of $I+P_{even}$ for each permutation are shown below.

```
1234: 16 1342: 4 1423: 4 
2143:  0 2314: 4 2431: 4
3124:  4 3241: 4 3412: 0
4132:  4 4213: 4 4321: 0
```

So your possible values for the determinant of $I+P_{even}$ are 0, 4 and 16.